# Create PLSQL function to return a table name

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a function to return a table value to put into another query.

this is the function i want to return the table name

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_TBL_NM (LYTID INTEGER)
AS 


BEGIN
    DECLARE
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE names_nt IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 ( 1000 ); 
    exec select vw into :names_nt from io_layout_views where layout_id = LYTID;
  RETURN (names_nt);
END GET_TBL_NM;
```

and this is where i wanna call the function:

```
select * from TABLE(my_function(args));
```

right now i am having issues getting the function to compile.

Comment: `return` statement in a procedure? `exec` (a SQL\*Plus command, not understood by PL/SQL) in the middle of a PL/SQL procedure? I'm afraid you skipped the first week of the PL/SQL course. Sorry, you can't write a valid function without learning the basics first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a `Procedure` with many syntax errors. You need to create a `Function` as shown below if your intention is to `Return` values from it.
Try this:

Type and tables

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE names_nt IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 ( 1000 ); 
Create  table io_layout_views (vw varchar2(1000),layout_id number);
insert into io_layout_views values ('AA',1);
insert into io_layout_views values ('BB',1);
```

--Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tbl_nm (
    lytid INTEGER
) RETURN names_nt AS
    v_var   names_nt := names_nt ();
BEGIN
    SELECT vw BULK COLLECT INTO
        v_var
    FROM io_layout_views
    WHERE layout_id = lytid;

    return(v_var);
END get_tbl_nm;
```

Execution:

```
select * from TABLE(get_tbl_nm(1));
```

Also you must note that when you are playing with `Table` functions, there are chances of getting performance issue if the collection is relatively large. Since the collection is large, result will not be shown until full collection is populated, To avoid this we use `PIPELINED` function as shown below. This function will return the result as soon as it gets available to the collection.

Pipelined Function: Read more [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tbl_nm (lytid INTEGER) 
    RETURN names_nt  PIPELINED
    AS
        v_var   names_nt := names_nt ();
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN (   
                   SELECT vw 
                    FROM io_layout_views 
                    WHERE layout_id = lytid
                   ) 
        LOOP
            PIPE ROW ( i.vw ); -- Building the resultset
        END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END get_tbl_nm;
```

Comment: ok i created the function but where do i declare these variables?
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE names_nt IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 ( 1000 ); 
Create  table io_layout_views (vw varchar2(1000),layout_id number);

Comment: These are database objects and has to be created under the scope of `SQL`. So simply open a `SQLDEVELOPER` or `SQLPLUS` or any interface which you use to connect to Orcle and execute those statements.

Comment: When i select * from GET_TBL_NM() i get the table value of IO_LAYOUT_VIEWS not the values of the table its holding

Comment: @C.Ward You must read my full answer. i already showed how you must select a record. Its like `select * from TABLE(get_tbl_nm(1));` since your function is expecting an input argument, you must pass it while executing it

Comment: so when i set it up like this: select * from TABLE(get_tbl_nm(1)) i get the value 'AA' not the data that is stored in the table AA

Comment: @C.Ward Yes.. You didnot write the code to retireve the value of table  `AA` assuming `AA` itself is a table. In that case you must write a native dynamic sql statement which will fetch the records of the table. Read about  native dynamic sql here - > https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/11_dynam.htm

Answer (score 2):

You have created the `procedure` which can not be used to return the values directly in the `SELECT` query as you have used.

You need to create the `UDT` independently which can be used in the `function` (PL/SQL) and also in the `query` (SQL) directly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NAMES_NT IS
    TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);
/
```

The function that you need to create must return the newly created type as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_TBL_NM (
    LYTID INTEGER
) RETURN NAMES_NT AS
    NAMES_NT_VALS   NAMES_NT; -- newly created UDT
BEGIN
    SELECT
        VW
    BULK COLLECT -- need to use BULK COLLECT
    INTO NAMES_NT_VALS
    FROM
        IO_LAYOUT_VIEWS
    WHERE
        LAYOUT_ID = LYTID;

    RETURN NAMES_NT_VALS;
END GET_TBL_NM;
```

Comment: When i select * from GET_TBL_NM() i get the table value of IO_LAYOUT_VIEWS not the values of the table its holding

Comment: Obviously!!!! If you want to find the data of the table then you will have to create the procedure with the dynamic cursor and it is not recommended at all. different tables have different numbers and types of columns. Which purpose will it solve?